# I/O operation on closed file error and how to fix it

Tags: python, io

The simple code below consists of a few I/O operations. I'm getting an **I/O operation on closed file** error and wondering what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

```
def externalSortStream(iterator, partId=0, reverse=False, keyfunc=None, serial=serializer, limit=10, batch=100):
"""
Given an iterator, returns an iterator of sorted elements (according to parameters). 

:param iterator: iterator. Expects (Key, Value).
:param keyfunc: function applied on the keykey.
:param reverse: Reverse default ordering if true. (default is ascending; reverse is descending) 
:param serializer: See README.
:param limit: memory limit.
:param batch: Number of elements to read at a time.
"""

all_runs = [] # can be used to hold a list of iterators
run = [] # used to hold the current run of elements

def load(fileobj):
    """
    Returns a generator object that outputs elements 
    from a serialized (saved) stream. Closes the file when done.

    :param fileobj: python object file
    """
    for _ in serial.load_stream(fileobj):
        yield _
    fileobj.close()

# TODO everywhere below 
n = 0
fileList = []
while True:
    c = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
    run += c
    # TODO

    if len(c) != batch:
        #last group
        run = sorted(run, key = lambda ele: ele[0])
        filename = get_sort_dir(partId, n)
        fileList.append(filename)
        with open(filename, "w+") as writeFile:
            serializer.dump_stream(run, writeFile)


        break

    if get_used_memory() > limit: # TODO

        run = sorted(run, key = lambda ele: ele[0])
        filename = get_sort_dir(partId, n)
        fileList.append(filename)
        with open(filename, "w+") as writeFile:
            serializer.dump_stream(run, writeFile)

        n += 1
        run = []

# TODO some cleanup stuff
for fi in fileList:
    #for each file, open, close, then delete
    with open(fi, "r") as current:

        all_runs.append(load(current))
    os.unlink(fi)

return heapq.merge(all_runs, key=lambda x: keyfunc(x[0]), reverse=reverse)
```

Full traceback:

ValueError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4e28c39b6fbb> in <module>()
      1 test_stream = ((i, i) for i in range(100))
----> 2 list(externalSortStream(test_stream, keyfunc=(lambda x: abs(50 - (x ** 2)))))[:10]

heapq3.py in merge(iterables, key, reverse)
    651     for order, it in enumerate(map(iter, iterables)):
    652         try:
--> 653             value = next(it)
    654             h_append([key(value), order * direction, value, it])
    655         except StopIteration:

<ipython-input-15-ec61ab2b349c> in load(fileobj)
     21         :param fileobj: python object file
     22         """
---> 23         for _ in serial.load_stream(fileobj):
     24             yield _
     25         fileobj.close()

serializers.py in load_stream(self, stream)
    137         while True:
    138             try:
--> 139                 yield self._read_with_length(stream)
    140             except EOFError:
    141                 return

serializers.py in _read_with_length(self, stream)
    154 
    155     def _read_with_length(self, stream):
--> 156         length = read_int(stream)
    157         if length == SpecialLengths.END_OF_DATA_SECTION:
    158             raise EOFError

serializers.py in read_int(stream)
    541 
    542 def read_int(stream):
--> 543     length = stream.read(4)
    544     if not length:
    545         raise EOFError

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: The error is in load(fileobj), which is the third to last line. A subrutine of load tries to read "current", which is passed into load().

Comment: Why don't you just add the traceback to your answer? It is really helpful.

Comment: Just added it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jobs When you add information to your question, you should paste it into the question - not through a link. Following the link you provided prompts me for my name before it shows me anything, and few (if any) people are going to give out their names just to answer an SO question when the info could have just as easily been included in the question in the first place.

Comment: I replaced the link with the full trackback.

Answer (score 0):

4th to last line:

```
 with open(fi, "r") as current:
```

needed to be changed to:

```
current = open(fi, "r")
```

That's it. That fixed my problem. load() closes **current**, and apparently I cannot close **current** inside the **with open() as ...** code segment for **current**.